# Call to undefined function apd_set_pprof_trace()

Tags: php, pecl

I have hundreds of php files which initiates mails throw SMTP server using "mail()" function. Now the this SMTP  is shutting down in few-days and we are asked to contact external EmailWebService to send mails. I have written  code to contact EmailWebService but here my problem starts,I have to search each file and substitute each "mail()" function call with my new function.

So i want to override the "mail()" function so that it invoke my function which can contact EmailWebService. To get this functionality i have installed APD ,it seems installed successfully but when i am try to use the function i am getting  "Call to undefined function apd_set_pprof_trace()"  error.

Could you please any one help me how get out of this issue within time or suggest different solution which avoid manual work of search and replace

Comment: grep and sed are your friends: http://vasir.net/blog/ubuntu/replace_string_in_multiple_files/

Comment: You should use this as an opportunity to refactor your code and have the mail sending done in one and only one place. So next time you only need to change it there, not everywhere.

Comment: @l-x - The most important point  i have to consider is nearly more than 10 developers code is executing on these files.If i do search and replace every atomic "mail" with new string it may leads to rename their function names,class names,argument name or may even effect inclusion files if they contain word "mail".

Comment: Do you use Namespaces in your code? If so, you could use a monkey patch.

Comment: Could you please provide an example